# How to inject js file in wpf webbrowser control in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, wpf, xaml

Hi I am using WPF WebBrowser control on my xaml page.
I have Html,Jquery,js, and css file in my html package.
I have to load html page in web browser control with all jquery library.
How can I inject this file?
I am writing code like this:

page.xaml.cs

```
 void wb_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string htmlPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "keyboardWidget\\test.html");
        string html = File.ReadAllText(htmlPath.ToString());
        webBrowser.NavigateToString(html);

    }
```

this is page.xaml:

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser"></WebBrowser>
```

I am getting error Like this.

[image]

Hi can anyone suggest what is the best way to inject js or jquery library.
if it's not possible in wpf web browser control then what control I should use.

Comment: How is the path to the JS file defined in the HTML? Relative/absolute?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem might not be that the JS script was not found by the WebBrowser control, but that the WPF WebBrowser control has compatibility issues with JSON.

Try including this script in your page and see if it resolves the problem:
[JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)

Download the json2.js and include this in the HTML of your page:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="json2.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks Glen, I have injected the json2.js file in my html but I am still getting same error.for json,Jquery and $

Comment: It still says JSON is undefined?

Comment: yes error message is same.I am able to load this html in IE and chrome.but bot in wpf webbrowser control

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to render html with js file in WPF WebBrowser control.

### Then I have used GeckoFx Control.

Add xulrunner ,Geckofx-Winforms.dll and Geckofx-Core.dll
then I had added page.xaml

```
 <Grid x:Name="gecoBrowser" Height="150" Width="735">
```

page.xaml.cs:

```
 Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "xulrunner");
            Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser myBrowser = new Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser();
            WindowsFormsHost host = new WindowsFormsHost();
            host.Child = myBrowser;
            gecoBrowser.Children.Add(host);
            string htmlPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "keyboardWidget\\test.html");
            myBrowser.Navigate("file:///" + htmlPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi found the answer of this Question :
inject js file in wpf web browser control.

first you have to update your IE in html like
in head of html:

```
 <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">
```

inject this jquery library:-

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

The latter:

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/json-is-undefined-with-jquery-min-2-0-3-on-ie-11

IE 11 mode registry:

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version